SFMC org migration
We have two sfmc orgs (Org A and Org B) on same stack, and we are looking to merge them. Can we also migrate Org A's dedicated IP to Org B and reuse it? Would there be any operational impacts of IP migration? We plan on reusing Org A's Sender Authentication Package/Private Domain

If both your orgs are residing on the same stack, moving the dedicated IP from A to B should not be a problem. You are not writing whether you plan on reusing your Sender Authentication Package/Private Domain from A to B, or whether this will just be a question of moving the IP.
If you plan on moving everything over (assuming your IP from org A is sufficiently warm), then nothing will be impacting your sender reputation. If you only move the IP and not the domains (i.e. you will be sending on org B from domains originally on Org B, using the combination of IP adresses from A and B) you might want to keep an eye on your performance first few weeks. I would recommend gradually introducing this migrated IP into your regular email sends over the course of these few weeks, avoiding the risk of it affecting your sender reputation.

Thanks! We will be migrating SAP as well. If we have active emails being sent to customer from Org A, would there be any impact on delivery during the migration?

@SarahCapps you might want to confirm this with Salesforce support, but I would not expect you to be able to use one SAP on both the old and the new environment in the transition period.
